# QT HTML with align not working

Tags: c++, qt

I need help with this. I have a PDF I am generating with `QTextDocument`, and I am using HTML to format it. I am making an invoice for a quote. However, I want the description of the part to remain in the place I put it, while the price be  right justified, it doesn't work in QT while its working in a normal HTML file. My code is as follows:

```
QTextDocument document;
QString test = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>help</title><style type='text/css'>.left{float: left;}.right{float: right;}</style></head><body><div class='left'>Span Left</div><div class='right'>Span Right</div></body></html>";
// document.setDefaultStyleSheet();
document.setHtml(test);
```

This will not let the text align and just uses div and puts one text above and below the other. Any suggestions?

Comment: What the UI component you are using to display the QTextDocument.

Answer (score 1):

```
QString test = " \
        <!DOCTYPE html> \
        <html> \
            <head> \
            <title>help</title> \
            </head> \
        <body> \
            <div align='left'>Span Left</div> \
            <div align='right'>Span Right</div> \
        </body> \
        </html>";
```

Try this and refer [Supported HTML Subset](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html#block-attributes)